# Ejecutar un programa de python

Tags: python

Como puedo ejecutar un script de python solo escribiendo en consola `#run < problem_file.in` siendo `problem_file.in` un documento cualquiera.

Ahorita ejecuto mi programa con `cat input | python a_star_incons.py` 
siendo `input` ese documento que les mencionaba.

Estoy usando linux con python 2.7.6 [GCC 4.8.2]

Comment: Por favor agrega detalles a tu pregunta, por ejemplo (y sin que sea una lista exhaustiva o completa): sistema operativo, versión de python, tipo de consola de comandos, permisos del archivo, etc. Edita tu pregunta siguiendo estas directivas: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No se si lo he entendido bien, veamos por lo que parece tienes un script al que le pasas un archivo como entrada y hace algo con el. ¿Lo que quieres es asignar una determinada extension al script para que alejecutar/abrir un archivocon esa extensión se llame al script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veo dos formas de hacerlo:

```
python a_star_incons.py < problem_file.in
```

O que tu script tenga permisos de ejecución y ejecutarlo así:

```
./a_star_incons.py < problem_file.in
```

Te sugiero que revises tu script, y quizás podrias hacer que este maneje el input del archivo como un parametro en la ejecución del mismo script, y que por ejemplo, te tire un mensaje de error cuando no le pases el nombre del archivo. La idea es que la ejecución sea:

```
./a_star_incons.py  problem_file.in
```

Comment: No vendría mal un pequeño ejemplo de cómo dar permisos de ejecución al script directamente, o de cómo aceptar un parámetro y leer el archivo internamente.